# Orbiting around the origin using a device's orientation

Tags: javascript, three.js, google-cardboard

I am trying to replicate the functionality of Google's Cardboard Demo "Exhibit" with three.js. I took the starting example straight from the [Chrome Experiments web page](https://vr.chromeexperiments.com/) and just dropped in code to draw a simple triangular pyramid in the `init` method:

```
function init() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  element = renderer.domElement;
  container = document.getElementById('example');
  container.appendChild(element);

  effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, 1, 0.001, 700);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
  scene.add(camera);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, element);
  controls.rotateUp(Math.PI / 4);
  controls.noZoom = true;
  controls.noPan = true;

  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 10, 30, 4, 1 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.updateMatrix();
  mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
  scene.add( mesh );

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
  light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
  scene.add( light );

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
  light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
  scene.add( light );

  light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
  scene.add( light );

  function setOrientationControls(e) {
    if (!e.alpha) {
      return;
    }

    controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
    controls.connect();
    controls.update();

    element.addEventListener('click', fullscreen, false);

    window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrientationControls, true);
  }
  window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrientationControls, true);

  window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
  setTimeout(resize, 1);
}
```

The `OrbitControls` method on desktop works perfectly: by dragging with the mouse, the screen orbits around the pyramid. On mobile using `DeviceOrientationControls` however, this effect is entirely lost and instead the camera moves freely at (0, 0, 0). I tried doing as a [previous question suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815662/rotating-object-instead-of-camera-with-deviceorientationcontrols) and replacing the `camera` with `scene` such that:

```
controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(scene);
```

however this does not work at all and nothing moves when the device is rotated. What do I need to change to replicate `OrbitControls` behavior with the motion captured by `DeviceOrientationControls`?

Comment: I am also trying to combine http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html with OrbitControls (swipe). So have deviceorientantion on PDA and OrbitControls on desktop. Highly curious about an answer to this one.

Comment: Related: What mobile are you using. I tested the controls_deviceorientation on Samsung S4 tablet and it does not work. There only the CSS3D "panorama" example works. However on the Samsung S4 mobile controls_deviceorientation work super nice. I am at loss of how to determine if a device will support controls_deviceorientation with webgl or needs CSS3D. So basically it could be that the device you are trying this on does not support it somehow. Does the CSS3D panorama example work for you on the mobile you are testing but not deviceorientation? http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_panorama

Comment: @lowtechsun `DeviceOrientationControls` and other things like the panorama example do work for me, it's just that I want to have the default behavior of `OrbitControls` but instead of using a mouse, I want it to orbit with the orientation of my phone. So I have an object centered on the screen, and as I move around in a circle, the object rotates with me and I can see it at any angle as if it was physically in front of me. Currently, `DeviceOrientationControls` does the opposite of this and puts me at the center of the circle with the objects around me instead of vice versa.

Comment: Is this sort of what you have in mind?  If so, I'll explain more.  http://novak.us/labs/UmDemo/

Comment: @ Brandon From your comment and Sean's example I can see what you are getting at. Sean's demo is class and I can use some use case for this. Consider this though. If people really like to see the opposite side of the object they will have to not only rotate the device but also be on the outer side of this rotation (arc of the circle) since the object is the centre of the circle. Is this really what you want? Nevertheless I am anticipating an answer to your question without a doubt. @ Sean if you could explain more that would be class, thank you.

Comment: @SeanNovak Yeah, that was pretty much what I was looking for, just without the automatic rotation or limits. Feel free to post it as an answer. @ lowtechsun You're right, it would usually be pretty awkward to have to move along the arc just to see the backside. Fortunately though, the app I'm designing is supposed to appear rather gimmick and I want people to feel as if the object is actually right in front of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a deviceorientation orbit controler, like you see on this demo, http://novak.us/labs/UmDemo/; It involves modifying the existing OrbitControls.js.

The file changes can be seen in this commit on github: https://github.com/snovak/three.js/commit/f6542ab3d95b1c746ab4d39ab5d3253720830dd3

I've been meaning to do a pull request for months.  Just haven't gotten around to it.  Needs a bunch of clean up.

You can download my modified OrbitControls.js here (I haven't merged in months either, results may vary): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snovak/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Below is how you would implement the modified OrbitControls in your own scripts:

```
this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, document.getElementById('screen') ) ;

            controls.tiltEnabled = true ;  // default is false.  You need to turn this on to control with the gyro sensor.

            controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.4; // radians
            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.6; // radians
            controls.noZoom = true ;

            // How far you can rotate on the horizontal axis, upper and lower limits.
            // If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
            controls.minAzimuthAngle = - Math.PI * 0.1; // radians
            controls.maxAzimuthAngle = Math.PI * 0.1; // radians

            this.UMLogo = scene.children[1];
            controls.target = UMLogo.position;
```

I hope that gets you where you want to be!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

To use the `DeviceOrientationControls` You must call `controls.update()` during your animation loop or the control will not update it's position based on device info.